# How to align items in both end in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I have a `td` with two `div`, what I want is to align these `div` in both ends.

```html
<td class="lefts">
  <div>
    <h4>VOUCHER </h4>
    <h4>DATE TIME </h4>
    <h4>SALESMAN</h4>
   <h4>CUSTOMER : </h4>
    <h4>CONTACT </h4>
    <h4>VAT / : </h4>
    <h4>ADDRESS </h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p> HELLO WORLD </P>
  </div>
</td>
```

Here's a visual representation of how I would like to align my `div`

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can use `flex` with `justify-content` having `space-between` as a value.

For eg (I've changed your markup a bit):

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <h4>VOUCHER</h4>
    <h4>DATE TIME</h4>
    <h4>SALESMAN</h4>
    <h4>CUSTOMER:</h4>
    <h4>CONTACT</h4>
    <h4>VAT:</h4>
    <h4>ADDRESS</h4>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>HELLO WORLD</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
  .lefts {
     display:flex;
     align-items:center; /* If you want to align vertically */
     justify-content:space-between;
     width:300px; /* example */
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- parent ! -->
<table>
  <td class="lefts">
    <div>
      <h4 >VOUCHER </h4>
      <h4>DATE TIME    </h4>
      <h4 >SALESMAN</h4>
      <h4>CUSTOMER : </h4>
      <h4 >CONTACT  </h4>
      <h4>VAT / : </h4>
      <h4 >ADDRESS </h4>
    </div>

    <div>
      <p> HELLO WORLD </p>
    </div>
  </td>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).